Change value on global string to null
I use a global variable:
String? globalDeviceVersion;

And I set the variable when I connect via bluetooth device and it works good.
The issue is when I want to 'reset' the global value and I have tried:
setState(() {
  globals.globalDeviceVersion == null;
});
print(globals.globalDeviceVersion);

and without state:
globals.globalDeviceVersion == null;
print(globals.globalDeviceVersion);

The print in both cases just prints the previous value and the global is not set to null.

In 1st case : the value of globals.globalDeviceVersion remains unchanged. The check globals.globalDeviceVersion == null; simply evaluates to true or false, but it doesn't modify the state.
For changing value you have to write globals.globalDeviceVersion = null;
same scenario in 2nd case.

Comparison vs. Assignment: The key difference is that == is a comparison operator that checks equality and does not assign a value. To assign a value, you should use =

Thanks guys! I had my suspicions that '==' was wrong!

Added working code as answer.

Try below code.
setState(() {
  globals.globalDeviceVersion = null;
});
print(globals.globalDeviceVersion);

and without state:
globals.globalDeviceVersion = null;
print(globals.globalDeviceVersion);


I think the issue here is you are comparing the globals.globalDeviceVersion to null not changing the value the code would be
setState(() {
  globals.globalDeviceVersion = null; //modify == to = only
});
print(globals.globalDeviceVersion);

